# EventToCommand or Attached Behaviour for Events in WPF?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, command, mvvm-light, attachedbehaviors

I was wondering What I should use for event in MVVM,EventToCommand or  Attached Behaviour ?
which one has better performance?

Answer (score 0):

It depends, 
If you are using the proper tools, the event to command will provide the routed command abilities meaning command can execute for vm and sub vms at once. and will work slower than a simple command as attached behavior that you're implementing.

So if you don't need this complex logic, or not using the proper tools to bind events and command it doesn't really matter.

In both cases you subscribe to event once, the real question is how many handlers do you need? When it's just one in the data scope, it really doesn't matter.